# Listing files in apache server

Tags: 14.04, apache2, browser, file-sharing

I have installed Apache server in my system running Ubuntu 14.04. When I type `localhost` or my IP address in the browser, it is displaying the Apache page. Instead of that page, I need to list the contents (folder/files) in `/var/www` directory. How do I configure it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to delete all files that have an index in der name. For example index.html or index.php. Because the webserver looks for this files and when it finds some he displays the site instead of the folder.
And I think in the newer versions of Apache the main site is in /var/www/html. So delete the file /var/www/html/index.html.

I hope this helps..

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way is to move the welcome page. Two things:

1. Apache on Ubuntu 14.04 uses `/var/www/html/` directory by default, so you can either start using that directory or change the Apache configuration to use `/var/www`.
2. The default page is `/var/www/html/index.html`. Rename it to something else, like `/var/www/html/apache-welcome.html`.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Apache documentation](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/DirectoryListings):

> When a directory is requested, Apache may be configured to send a
>   particular file within that directory automatically. This is
>   configured with the DirectoryIndex directive. It can list one or more
>   files that Apache should search for in the directory, with the first
>   existing file being returned to the client. For example:
>
> DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.php welcome.html

If request point to directory that doesn't have file form [DirectoryIndex](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex), Apache use [mod_autoindex](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_autoindex.html) and can returns a list of directory contents.

**mod_autoindex** can be enabled/disabled using Options directive. For example:

```
   <Directory /var/www>
      Options +Indexes
   </Directory>
```

allow Apache to return directory contents of `/var/www` if it doesn't contains **DirectoryIndex** file.

> To prevent directory listings (for security purposes, for example),
>   you should remove the Indexes keyword from every Options directive in
>   your configuration file. Or to prevent them only for a single
>   directory, you can use:

```
    <Directory /var/www/images>  
        Options -Indexes 
    </Directory>
```

So, you should check your apache configuration file and choose which Options you want to use and on which directory.

Comment: how do you link this to a virtual directory like http://www.bla.com/files  ?  I mean where do you put the /files bit ?

Comment: @user230910  You should find out where bla.com/files location is mapped on filesystem, normally it is defined inside VirtualHost configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Often there is /etc/httpd/conf.d/welcome.conf file and override your configuration about index file to open . I prefer to delete it and now I've the list of files and directory for all sites haven't and index file.

Comment: I'm not sure this answer even makes sense. Can you edit your answer to clarify?